# For Loop not working properly inside onPostExecute

Tags: android, for-loop

Where i am doing mistake, using below code to `create event` into `Calendar` (fetching date from server using `JSON` Parsing)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < appointmentsArrayList.size(); i++) {

        try {
            Log.d("check", appointmentsArrayList.get(i).getDate());
            eventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(appointmentsArrayList.get(i).getDate());
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: show your json example

Comment: Call `addToCalender()` method in your `for` loop. As you are calling it outside the loop, it creates the event only for the last value.

Comment: call addToCalender(); inside your for loop

Comment: post some more information, like where you create events

Comment: @RichSala check my updated above... now event not getting AppointmentsActivity.java

Comment: Your implementation is not clear to me. Where do you use the `eventDate` variable? Your code doesn't show, the lines which actually create an event in the calendar.

Comment: @RichSala I have posted whole addToCalendar() code, please check now

Comment: @PrerakSola I have posted whole addToCalendar() code, please check now

Comment: make a note Calendar.MONTH is having values starting from `0`

Comment: I don't understand how you use `eventDate` variable in the for-loop (= outside `addToCalender()` method) , while its declared inside `addToCalender()` method? are you sure that you have only one variable named `eventDate` in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call addToCalender(); inside your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < appointmentsArrayList.size(); i++) {

    try {
        Log.d("check", appointmentsArrayList.get(i).getDate());
        eventDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").parse(appointmentsArrayList.get(i).getDate());
        addToCalender();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: check my updated above... now event not getting AppointmentsActivity.java